# How to convert txt file to html using perl

Tags: perl, scripting, storage

I have run some scripts to generate storage capacity report and configuration settings report using perl.  I would like send this report to my mail id in html using perl.

Please note that I am new to perl programming.

Comment: How does your  'report' look like? Something that can be depicted in tabular format? Edit your question with more information please.

Comment: Are you trying to convert txt file to html or just want to send an html email with attachment of text file?

Comment: You need to separate your question, right now it's unclear. You need to 1)convert text to html using perl 2)send a file to e-mail using perl? Is that correct?

Comment: @john doe, Yes you are correct, I need to convert text to html using perl and send a file to email using perl.

Comment: @iMan, Yes my report is in tabular format.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vague, so it's hard to be of much help. This might point you in the right direction though.

You basically have three tasks here.

1. Parse your report into data structures.
2. Use your data structures to generate an HTML document.
3. Send the HTML document by email.

I can't really help with step 1 as I know nothing about your report. If you have your file in CSV format, then [Text:CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) will be useful to you. It's worth pointing out that if you're generating this report, then you could generate it in a format that is easier to parse - JSON, for example.

For step 2, I'd recommend a templating engine. I'd use the [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/release/Template-Toolkit), but other options are available. The idea is that you create a template file that contains all of your HTML with "tags" where you want your variable data to go. On a simple level it might look something like this:

```
<html>
  <head><title>Some Title</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Some Title</h1>
    <p>Blah...</p>
    <table>
[% FOREACH row IN data -%]
      <tr><td>[% row.value %]</td><td>[% row.another_value %]</td></tr>
[% END -%]
    <table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Assuming that's in a file called `email.tt` and you have your data in an array of hashes called `@data`, then you'd process the template like this:

```
use Template;

@data = ({
  value => 'something',
  another_value => 'something else',
}, {
  value => 'something',
  another_value => 'something else',
});

my $tt = Template->new;

$tt->process('email.tt', { data => \@data }, \$email_body)
  or die $tt->error;
```

That will give you your expanded HTML in `$email_body`. And that brings us to step 3.

I recommend [Email::Stuffer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Stuffer) for sending email.

```
use Email::Stuffer;

Email::Stuffer->from     ('you@example.com')
              ->to       ('someone_else@example.com')
              ->html_body($email_body)
              ->send;
```